# Javascript window.open from a different directory

Tags: javascript

I want to add an onClick() function to my HTML elements, so when they are clicked, the user will see another HTML file in the same tab. I have already found a way to do this when my js file and the target HTML file are located in the same directory. But I wanted to create a folder for my js files and so I needed to be able to give relative address according to my js file to the target HTML file.
Currently, my code is :

```
function test(){
    window.open('login.html', '_self');
}
```

I wanted something like this (although, it does not work) :

```
function test(){
    window.open('../arbitraryFolder/arbitraryFile.html', '_self');
}
```

Thanks.

Folder structure is something like this :
[image]

inside arbitraryFolder:

[image]

and my js file is inside the hs folder :

[image]

Comment: You have to pass the Full url like if your url is like example.com then you have to use as `window.open('http://example.com/arbitraryFolder/arbitraryFile.html', '_self');` then it will work definitely

Comment: @HaritsinhGohil Thanks, But I want to address locally

Comment: You can also enter local address in the place of example.com

Comment: **Please share the folder structure with us.** However, my guess would be to remove `../`, as it goes one level up in the tree, and that might not be what you want...

Comment: Thanks. It solved the issue. Sorry about the folder structure. I though It's enough that I mentioned ../ so that it means arbitraryFolder is in the parent directory.

Comment: What exactly does the code do when you say "it does not work"?

Comment: @user202729 It did nothing. I was coding on Webstorm. When working with directories, it would suggest names of files and folders. This time, it didn't. So I was convinced that It does not work that way.
I had confused it with addressing other external files, such as scripts or styles. It turned out that they are not the same.